# How to truncate text but backwards?

Tags: lua

I want to achieve something like this:
[image: 1]

I give function a string that should be trunctated and a maximum number of characters.

```
local function TruncateBackwards(str, maxChars)
  --Code
end

print(TruncateBackwards("this text should be truncated", 15)) -- ld be truncated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string.sub`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.sub) for this:

```lua
local function TruncateBackwards(str, maxChars) return str:sub(-maxChars) end
print(TruncateBackwards("this text should be truncated", 15)) -- ld be truncated
```

this also makes your own function, `TruncateBackwards`, pretty obsolete:

```lua
print(("this text should be truncated"):sub(-15)) -- ld be truncated
```

no index math is needed as Lua indices are one-indexed and `string.sub` supports negative indices relative to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

With gsub() you can do this with the pattern: `'..%s%w+%s%w+$'`
...or with 15 Dots before the `$`: `'...............$'`
...or with 15 repetitions of a dot before the `$`: `('.'):rep(15) .. '$'`

```
local txt, count = ("this text should be truncated"):gsub('..%s%w+%s%w+$', '')
print(txt)
-- That replaces the capture 'ld be truncated' with nothing
-- Output: this text shou
-- With match() and same pattern you can do the opposite
print(("this text should be truncated"):match('..%s%w+%s%w+$'))
-- Output: ld be truncated
```

See: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1